# Intellij Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder'

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

can someone help me on this error please. I am using intellij 14.1.4,how can I fixed this error , I tried to search here in S.O but I could not get answers to solve my problem, so I'll just post my problem.

`08-16 18:44:23.090    9676-9676/com.example.myfuseprovider E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
08-16 18:44:23.090    9676-9676/com.example.myfuseprovider E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
08-16 18:44:23.098    9676-9676/com.example.myfuseprovider E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
08-16 18:44:23.114    9676-9676/com.example.myfuseprovider E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfuseprovider/com.example.myfuseprovider.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7895000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7895000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzad(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.myfuseprovider.MyActivity.servicesOK(MyActivity.java:34)
            at com.example.myfuseprovider.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

And here is my manifest file

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.myfuseprovider"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>

   

    <permission
            android:name="com.example.myfuseprovider.permissions.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"
            />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myfuseprovider.permissions.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-feature
          android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
          android:required="true"  />


    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="--my key--" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add follow to your manifest:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: it removes the run excetipiton,but still it has error `﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder'`